# Modify Word.EmailOptions without instantiating MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto, openxml-sdk

I know how to set Word.EmailOptions via the Word object model in VBA and VSTO.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.emailoptions

Is it possible to use the OpenXML SDK to set them? Does anyone know where they are stored? I'd like to modify them without instantiating MS Word.

-- Edit --

Specifically:

```
emailOptions.ComposeStyle.Font.Name
emailOptions.ComposeStyle.Font.Size
emailOptions.ComposeStyle.Font.Color
```

and the same for:

```
emailOptions.ReplyStyle
```

Comment: What are the exact options that you want to modify?

Comment: Dimitri, please see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options are stored in `ComposeFontComplex` and `ComposeFontSimple` registry values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings`

The format is not documented, of course.